# Validate each element of xml against one element of xsd using stax parser

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I have coded validation of entire xml against xsd using validator.validate(new StAXSource(reader) method but I want to validate individual element against some element of xsd and report an error if its invalid and continue validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate an individual element if that element corresponds to a top level element definition in the schema. Using DOM you would simply create a `DOMSource` on the particular `Element` and call `validator.validate()`. Not sure if/how it works with Stax.

Comment: Strictly speaking, "... can validate an individual element if that element corresponds to a top level element definition in the schema" is not always true (as in the only way possible). Abstract elements come to mind immediately. An arbitrary named element (for which no global declaration exist) can also be validated if the definition matching the qualified name in an existing xsi:type attribute can be resolved.